# Sharing url on facebook do not fetch image/title/description

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I apologize if i am making a duplicate post but I tried searching the forum but could not find same problem reported before, one post is alike but marked ambiguous and incomplete.

I am facing a problem that whenever i share the url on facebook it does not fetch the Image/Title/Description from the page
also in the Like button plugin, Like Button is working fine but not the Share button in same plugin
Share Button plugin is not working at all

since long this was working fine but stopped working for some time

the solutions/fixes I tried are

1. Used the opengraph **meta tags**
2. **validated it on linter** (no errors bur response 206)
3. I created a very simple html with meta tags only and hello world in body, the required information but still response remains 206 (I guess its not related to first X bytes/40k limit), and symptoms remain as above
4. Image also meets the og requirements of ratio and size
5. Refreshing each change with Linter/Debugger so I assume there is no cache to create problems

im using following meta tags in head

```
<meta property="og:site_name"   content="my site"/>
<meta property="og:title"   content="my page title"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="post description goes here"/>
<meta property="og:url"     content="http://www.dufferistan.com/test.html"/>
<meta property="fb:admins"  content="1175346859" />
<meta property="fb:app_id"  content="203931736308566" />
<meta property="og:image"   content="http://s2.postimg.org/v5go7q1vt/duffbloglogo.png" />
<meta property="og:type"    content="article" />
```

with only "hello world" in body

the only problem seems is "**Response Code  206**" from Linter/Debugger

- even if i remove fb:admins/fb:app_id, result remains same
- primary objective is to get image/title/desc when url pasted on fb

If anybody can please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your page at og:url : http://www.dufferistan.com/test.html is the page which should contain these meta tags. It doesn't seem to have any tags currently.

Answer (score 0):

Bacause you dont use code to get cerent detail . you must know a litter bit about the php code . here is the example code . hope can help you

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
<link rel="image_src" href="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
<?php $link_image = $image; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $base . 'image/logo_banner.png'; ?>" />
<link rel="image_src" href="<?php echo $base . 'image/logo_banner.png'; ?>" />
<?php $link_image = $base . 'image/logo_banner.png'; ?>
<?php } ?>
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg/jpg/png"> 
<meta property="og:image:width" content="250"> 
<meta property="og:image:height" content="250">
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
<?php if ($description) { ?>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo $base; ?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?$URL="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; echo $URL;?>" />
<?php if ($description) { ?>
<meta itemprop="description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
```

problem solve